# Issues passing variables inside of command substitution in bash

Tags: bash, sorting, variables, command-substitution

I want to run `sort` and pass `LC_COLLATE=C` to it. The output is then going to be stored in a variable.

I wrote this:

```
var="$(LC_COLLATE=C sort 'aaa
Abc')"
```

But, oddly enough, I receive `sort: No such file or directory`. I most definately have `sort` on my system; `command -v sort` says it's in `/usr/bin/`. I also tried changing `sort` to specifically say `/usr/bin/sort` but that didn't work either.

I know command substitution chokes up on variables sometimes, but I thought that had to do with taking variables out of them, not the other way around.

Edit: This seems to also happen outside of command substitution. Running:

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort 'aaa
Abc'
```

also gives me the same error. I find that, if I don't use multiline quotes, the error goes away, but I can't explain why.

Comment: sort needs a file argument, not a string. If you want to pass a string, you can use various things, e.g. `echo -e "aaa\nAbc" | sort`

Comment: Try `var=$(LC_COLLATE=C sort <<< $'aaa\nAbc')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `sort` cannot find is the file named `aaa<newline>Abc`. If you want to send the string to the standard input of `sort`, use a here string:

```
var=$(LC_COLLATE=C sort <<< 'aaa
Abc')
```

or a here document:

```
var=$(LC_COLLATE=C sort << EOF
aaa
Abc
EOF
)
```

Comment: The problem I realized I originally had was that I was replacing one of `sort`'s switches with a variable. When the variable was unset, I would get that error. Thanks for your help!